# Solve an exercise problem from purescript-by-example book

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, purescript

I'm trying to solve a problem given in chapter 11 of the book purescript-by-example by Phil Freeman.

It depends on a previous problem, and the description of the problem is,

> In these exercises, we will use the Reader monad to build a small
> library for rendering documents with indentation. The "global
> configuration" will be a number indicating the current indentation
> level:

```
type Level = Int

type Doc = Reader Level String
```

1. Write a function line which renders a function at the current indentation level. Your function should have the following type:

   `line :: String -> Doc`

> Hint: use the ask function to read the current indentation level. The
> power function from Data.Monoid may be helpful too.

2. Use the local function to write a function

   `indent :: Doc -> Doc`

   which increases the indentation level for a block of code.
3. Use the sequence function defined in Data.Traversable to write a function

   `cat :: Array Doc -> Doc`

   which concatenates a collection of documents, separating them with new lines.
4. Use the runReader function to write a function

   `render :: Doc -> String`

   which renders a document as a String.

You should now be able to use your library to write simple documents, as follows:

```
render $ cat
  [ line "Here is some indented text:"
  , indent $ cat
      [ line "I am indented"
      , line "So am I"
      , indent $ line "I am even more indented"
      ]
  ]
```

My solution is,

```
line :: String -> Doc
line input = do 
    space <- ask 
    pure $ (power " " space) <> input <> "\n" 
    
indent :: Doc -> Doc
indent = local (\l -> l+1)  

cat :: Array Doc -> Doc
cat docs = do
    lines <- sequence docs 
    pure (foldr (<>) "" lines)

render :: Doc -> String
render doc = runReader doc 0 

printDoc :: Doc -> Effect Unit
printDoc = log <<< render
```

Can someone tell me how to solve the problem using Monad Transformers like ReaderT and WriterT ?

The problem description goes like this

> Use the ReaderT and WriterT monad transformers to reimplement the document printing library which we wrote earlier using the Reader monad.
>
> Instead of using line to emit strings and cat to concatenate strings,
> use the Array String monoid with the WriterT monad transformer, and
> tell to append a line to the result. Use the same names as in the
> original implementation but ending with an apostrophe (').

PS. Haskell solution is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I have arrived at a solution using ReaderT and Writer monad transformers.

```
type Doc' = ReaderT Level (Writer (Array String)) Unit

line' :: String -> Doc'
line' input = do 
        space <-  ask 
        lift $ tell $ [(power " " space) <> input] 

indent' :: Array Doc' -> Doc' 
indent' docs =  local (_+1)  (sequence_ docs)

render' :: Array Doc' -> String 
render' docs = joinWith "\n" (execWriter $ runReaderT (sequence docs) 0)

printDoc' :: Array Doc' -> Effect Unit 
printDoc' = log <<< render'
```

In spago repl, you can check the output by

```
> :paste
… printDoc' 
…    [ line' "Here is some indented text:"
…    , indent' 
…        [ line' "I am indented"
…        , line' "So am I"
…        , indent'
…          [ line' "I am even more indented"
…          ]
…        ]
…    ]
… (press Ctrl + D to run)
Here is some indented text:
 I am indented
 So am I
  I am even more indented
```